# How do you calculate the probability of $P(X=x)$ for a density function $p(x)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

There is a bus that come every 10 min. What is the probability that a person come at the exact moment the bus arrives if $p(x)$ is $\frac1{20}$ between 0 and 30, where $x$ is the time? I think its $\frac3{10}$, but how do you get this? When I integrate the function I get $\frac x{20}$, but the probability for $P(X=0)$ is $\frac0{20}$. $P(X=10) = \frac{10}{20}$, and so on. I think there is something I didn't quite understand.

My initial thought was that $P(X=0)$ is so small that we don't take it into account, but that doesn't seem to make sense, because it's $\frac1{20}$ between 0 and 30. However, I think the analogy is not very good, because it has to be exactly at time $x$, so if $x=1.0000000002$, the person should also come at the exact same time, so the bus analogy isn't really good, because the bus waits a certain time and we often run to catch the bus.

Comment: If by $p(x)$ you mean the density function of the arrival time of the person, then there is a problem since density should integrate to $1$, and $\frac{1}{20}$ in a $30$ minute interval integrates to more than $1$. That issue aside, if $X$ has continuous distribution, then $\Pr(X=a)=0$ for any $a$.

Comment: it's 0? ah ok so we ignore that i guess. thats why the questions always give us like an interval instead of a value a, right?

Comment: Yes, for random variables with continuous distribution, point probabilities are useless, and it is intervals that matter. And as you point out in your post, in practice a bus will not leave the *instant* it arrives, so for catching the bus intervals are the relevant thing. But the question said "exact moment" and thus the answer is $0$.